sign of slope ratio in limiter function
I'm studying Flux Limiters. I have the questions

Is the slope $r_i$ allowed to be negative?
If so, why is the region $r_i < 0$ not shown in the Sweby diagram at the bottom of that page?

Thanks.
Edit: Is it because we can deduce the behavior of $\phi(-r)$ using the symmetry property $\frac{\phi(r)}{r} = \phi(\frac{1}{r})$?
Edit2: just realised my first edit doesn't make sense
